# The details I put into my login form code are returned as incorrect even though they are,why?

Tags: php, pdo

Here is my code:

```html
<?php


session_start();

include_once('../includes/connection.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
 
}else{
 
 if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
  $username= $_POST['username'];
  $password= md5($_POST['password']);
  
  
  if(empty($username) or empty($password)) {
   
   $error = 'All fields are required!';
   
   
  }else{
   $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ? user_password = ?");
   
   $query->bindValue(1, $username);
   $query->bindValue(2, $password);
   
   $query->execute();
   
   
   $num = $query->rowCount();
   
   if ($num==1){
    
    
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
    
    
    
   }else{
    
   $error='Incorrect details!';
   
   }
   
  }
  
  
  
 }
 
 
 
?>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>CMS Tutorial</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/style.css" /> 
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
<a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>


  



<?php if(isset($error)) { ?>

<small style="color:#aa0000;"><?php echo $error; ?></small>

<?php } ?> 


  
  <form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
                  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
                  <input type="submit" value="Login" />      
  </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>


<?php
 
 
 
}



?>
```

I have no clue where my mistake is,tried finding an error but I could not find It,the most recent code that I entered into the code was "}else{ $query = $pdo-> etc.."but I do not think there is any mistake there...If someone could help me I would be really grateful!Also you guys do not have to send me the entire code answer a simple answer or a hint would be helpful. :D!

Comment: Your query needs AND before user_password=? .also please do not use md5 for passwords. Use php's built in password_hash and password_verify

Comment: Wow that was fast thank you! Such a dumb mistake :D

Comment: you're not going live with this, are you?

Comment: @CodeGodie `if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))` is valid. That syntax with the comma separator however, doesn't work with `empty()`. Edit: You deleted the comment I was replying to.

Comment: @CodeGodie no it will not you can pass multiple var check [documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: caught that, I pasted the wrong info.. Thx

Comment: @Fred -ii-  you'd be surprised that this is in production

Comment: @Akintunde *Scary*.

Comment: ***You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your query needs an AND:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ? AND user_password = ?");
```

Comment: Thank you works like a charm! Ill mark your comment as an answer in ten minutes! Thank you again!